# Calculate Nash-Sutcliff-Efficiency

Tags: python

I have two arrays which shapes are both(220, 6), how to calculate the NSE(Nash-Sutcliff-Efficiency)?
I know how to calculate when it has one column, as follows:

```
denominator = np.sum((a1 - np.mean(a1)) ** 2)
numerator = np.sum((a2 - a1) ** 2)
nse_val = 1 - numerator / denominator
```

Does this also work for arrays which have more columns?

Comment: Does each column represent the same feature or different features? Do you want the column-wise value or the value for all numbers in the flattened arrays? _"Does this also work for arrays which have more columns"_: why not find out by trying it yourself for a dataset for which you know the answers?

Answer (score 4):

Here is function I use for Nash-Sutcliffe Efficiency (NSE) calculation,

```
def nse(predictions, targets):
    return (1-(np.sum((targets-predictions)**2)/np.sum((targets-np.mean(targets))**2))
```

Tested for 1d and 2d numpy arrays without any NaN's.

Comment: Your edit makes no difference to the result. `(a-b)**2 == (b-a)**2`

Comment: Also your code is identical to OP's, just inside a function https://tio.run/##fZDBbsMwCIbvPAVHEyVtnd0m7Vkm1LAuUowt25nUp8/sNImqHuoLRnz8/BDu@dfrx7KMLviYUWcX7sgJNQAM8oOaxBruW2RLn4CDqHejcvYRvwp0SrMzhi12NXHCWhIibBrsCaqcxFe4L3CBDibJ9x9PhVhVjo7z8zDAKHmOutOHOROiDOM1j15Ti5njTXKqTsvbWoztzD58A7qnLmqans6vwL7NrrhSRAD5sUpkHbzbgjH2cmlLHcLbKnBKUq8cTjxN18kX/@uBQ7FO7WOf@qVl@Qc

Comment: Just checked. Agree. edited to make it consistent with literature.

Comment: typo error : and extra "(" on return is not needed. it should be :   
```def nse(predictions, targets):
    return 1-(np.sum((targets-predictions)**2)/np.sum((targets-np.mean(targets))**2))
```